# R studio: error message when I was trying to intall a package

Tags: r, package

I'm very new to R studio.
Was trying to do my assignment, that need to install a package. But when I was doing so, an error message came out

Here is the whole thing including what I put in:

> install.packages('Seurat')
> trying URL 'cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/Seurat_4.0.5.zip' Content type 'application/zip' length 2779717 bytes (2.7 MB) downloaded 2.7 MB package ‘Seurat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked The downloaded binary packages are in C:\Users\tengb\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSImCvj\downloaded_packages

Warning message: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/tengb/OneDrive/??": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

It was weird that it shows some location of Onedrive, but I was not trying to install it in onedrive at all. I also tried to set the working directory to a folder that does not have any weird characters but, this warning message still show up.

Comment: (1) One should not install package into a onedrive directory, it seems to cause lots of problems. Install into a non-onedrive path, a path without spaces in it, and then move that (if you must) into the onedrive path. (2) `error != warning`. I think your message is actually an error, but you list it as a warning, please do not confuse the two. (3) This is not reproducible without any sort of information. What did you try to install? What are the rest of the errors/warnings? What is your R-version and OS? Does this really have something to do with the [tag:rstudio]? (My guess: no.)

Comment: Yes, this is the weirdest thing, that I was not install packages to onedrive at all, but the R studio keep showing me this message. I have tried to use .libPaths to set the location where I want the package to be, but this message still shows up.

Comment: Your question suggests none of that. We don't know what you typed before this point, we don't know that you are not installing to onedrive, we don't know what you tried to install.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your responses. I was using a R 4.1.2, my OS is windows 10.  I was trying to install a package for data analysis for RNA sequencing, it's called "Seurat" (https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/install.html).

Comment: Here is the whole thing:      > install.packages('Seurat')
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/Seurat_4.0.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2779717 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

package ‘Seurat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\tengb\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSImCvj\downloaded_packages
Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:/Users/tengb/OneDrive/??": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: Please put that in your question